# close image after view in python

Tags: python, image

I want to open an image from python for the user to view and then close it via a python command.If i use PIL it calls an external program and the image can't close from python.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpouse you can use [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt). Some example of usage:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    if len(app.arguments()) < 1:

        sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s <image file> \n" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)

    image = QImage(app.arguments()[1])
    if image.isNull():
        sys.stderr.write("Failed to read image: %s\n" % app.arguments()[1])
        sys.exit(1)

    label = QLabel()
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
    label.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```